# ¿Como guardar y mostrar un ArrayList tipo objeto en sharedpreferences de un activity? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, json, sharedpreferences, gson

Ayuda con un problema que posiblemente sea simple pero estoy comenzando con android studio y no manejo todo muy bien. Trabajo en esta app con sharedpreferences y no me guarda nada.

Tengo un ArrayList que genero incrementalmente desde mi MainActivity, la cual recibo en otro activity, pero necesito guardar dicho ArrayList en sharedpreferences con la intencion de cerrar la app y al volverla a abrir encontrar los mismos items de objetos generados.

Tengo esto en mi Segundo Activity, aqui recibo la lista e implemento Gson pero aun asi no me la guarda al reiniciar la app y entrar a este activity no muestra nada.

```
public class HoyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView L_datos;
    private ImageButton btn_atras;
    private   ArrayList<Actividades> lista_tareas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hoy);
        
            loadData(); //cargo los datos del metodo loadData
        
        L_datos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mi_lista);
        btn_atras = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_atras);

        Bundle objetoEnviado=getIntent().getExtras();
        lista_tareas = null;

        if(objetoEnviado!=null){
            lista_tareas=(ArrayList<Actividades>) objetoEnviado.getSerializable("clave");

            saveData(); //guardo los datos

            //la muestra
            ArrayAdapter<Actividades> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Actividades>(HoyActivity.this, R.layout.custom, lista_tareas);
            L_datos.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        btn_atras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HoyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveData(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if(lista_tareas != null ){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(lista_tareas);
            editor.putString("task list", json);
            editor.apply();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lista vacia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lista guardada", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", "vacio");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Actividades>>(){}.getType();
        lista_tareas = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Guardar una lista de objetos en preferencias.**

Veo que usas `Gson` por lo que esta tarea puede ser sencilla, a partir de tu lista de objetos crea un `json`:

```
String jsonListaTareas = new Gson().toJson(lista_tareas);
```

Crea preferencia y guarda la lista en la preferencia:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();            
editor.putString("jsonListaTareas", jsonListaTareas );
editor.apply();
```

---

**Obtener una lista de objetos de preferencias.**

En este caso, se realiza el proceso inverso, se obtiene el .json que contiene los objetos de la preferencia y este valor es convertido a una lista de objetos.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
 Gson gson = new Gson(); // Se instancia Gson.
 //Obtiene datos (json)
 String jsonListaTareas = sharedPreferences.getString("jsonListaTareas", "");
 //Convierte json  a JsonArray.
String json = new Gson().toJson(objetos);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

//Convierte JSONArray a Lista de Objetos.
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myObject>>(){}.getType();
List<Actividades>  lista_tareas = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Comment: Me puede servir asi que muchas gracias, pero no me reconoce el putString ni el .commit al guardar la lista de objetos en preferencias

Comment: Perdón, me faltaron unas lineas, revisa el código de nuevo.